# Quasiconcavity of a squared function

Tags: functions

Let $f$ be a function defined on $R^2$, and $f^2$ is quasiconcave, is there such $f$ that is not quasiconcave?

I understand the definition of quasiconcavity and I know that when $f$ is quasiconcave then $f^2$ doesn't have to be (for example $f(x,y)=-x^2-y^2$, but does the opposite hold? It seems to me that $f$ would need to be a non-negative function that changes its quasiconcavity when squared, and it seems to me that such function does not exist, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample is $f(x) = -e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$.

$f^2(x) = e^{-2(x^2+y^2)}$ is quasiconcave because the level sets $\{ (x, y) \mid f^2(x, y) \ge a \}$ are the full plane, a closed disk, or empty, i.e. they are always a convex set.

But the level sets $\{ (x, y) \mid f(x, y) \ge a \}$ are the *exterior* of a disk for $0 < a < 1$, which shows that $f$ is not quasiconcave.